# How to set pass api key within NSURLRequest in iOS?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, nsurlrequest

as of now I have it like so:

```
NSURLRequest *Request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: reqURLStr]];
    NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: Request returningResponse: &resp error: &error];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return responseString;
```

and I call it like so:

```
NSString *stripeCustomerRequestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/%@",stripeCustomerId];

        // NSString for the return of the tax in decimal form
        NSString *customerInformation = [self retrieveStripeCustomer:stripeCustomerRequestURL];
```

I am getting this error which I know I need to pass the api key but how can I?

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not considered secure to be using your Stripe Secret API key from code that runs on a client device (iOS / Android apps, desktop apps, etc). As soon as you include your API key in a shipped binary, you can assume someone will inspect your binary and be able to extract the strings from it, including your API key thus compromising it.

Your API key should only be used on a server that you control. Your iOS app can call endpoints on your server and in turn your server will call out to Stripe.